# Knowing the error during system loads

Tags: error-handling

Sometimes when the system loads it shows an error in a rush and we are not able to even notice or read it to the full.
Is there any way in terminal or log file to see such an error ?
For example mounting errors,hardware errors etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to look in two logfiles:

- `/var/log/syslog` This is the place where you should look for hardware/mounting and also mostly any kind of errors. Look for lines containing **kernel: [xxxxxxxxx]**, where xxxxxxx is the kernel uptime (time elapsed since boot) when the message was logged.
- `/var/log/boot.log` This is the place where you should look for services failed to start. (This file contains terminal control escape sequences, so if you just `cat` it to a terminal it will be nicer than opening it in a text editor, i.e. `fails` will be printed in red.)

Answer (score 0):

Boot Chart for LInux is a simple way to automatically make a chart consisting of the applications your computer runs at boot, with the time it takes to load each app.

Run the below command on terminal to install bootchart,

```
sudo apt-get install bootchart
```

After you computer boots, you will find the boot charts in the `/var/log/bootchart` folder.

you can also see `/var/log/boot.log` file for booting issues.